# Programming hardware interrupts in code running in Windows

Tags: windows, assembly

I am experimenting with a simple kernel, and I am pretty blank on this area. 
Can I program the PIC and change interrupt service routines from inside a Windows program? (I need to test the code on SOME platform)

And if yes, is using "out " instructions with absolute port addresses valid in protected mode? Might be a stupid question, but I recall that I could NOT "out" to the parallel port without a kernel mode DLL. Is this different for the address of the PIC?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Protected mode doesn't mean user mode, is that what you meant?

Comment: No.  I mean that to access the parallel port from a user mode program I had to load a kernel mode DLL which almost a device driver. User mode is a collection of access rules, whereas protected mode is a state that the CPU is put into to provide linear memory mapping and deny a process access to any memory that is was not granted explicit access to. In short. Nice of you to assume I am an idiot because I don't have experience doing hardware interrupts :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean or what you're trying to do. Are you trying to unit-test embedded code under windows before programming it onto the PIC? Do you not have the ability to test it directly on the PIC yet?

Comment: Or you're not even doing embedded programming and PIC is Intel's word for "interrupt controller"... lol.

Comment: I don't assume you're an idiot, but it does sound as though you're a bit confused.  In 32-bit Windows, the CPU is *always* running in protected mode.  In 64-bit Windows, the CPU is always running in long mode.  (I'm not counting the early phases of the boot sequence, of course.)  User mode and kernel mode are Windows concepts, implemented via the CPU support for privilege levels, sometimes referred to as "rings".

Comment: At any rate, you can't use `out` in user mode, and while you can use it in kernel mode, you're not supposed to.  (Messing with the PIC in particular is pretty likely to crash Windows.)  Instead, run your kernel in a virtual machine, so that Windows doesn't get in your way.

Comment: I assume that the PIC is part of some type of external project board. Usually these will include a software tool set that lets you operate the PIC from Windows, perhaps via a serial port, using the standard Windows serial port driver. The point here is you shouldn't need to be writing your own Windows interface to work with the PIC project board.

Comment: Didn't try this on newer systems, but on XP you could make a 16bit application that ran in a virtual 8086 real mode. There you could write a custom ISR, and write a pointer to it directly into IVT. `out` worked as well. You were, of course, limited to 8086 instructions and and 1MB address space, but should be more than enough to test your ISRs.

Comment: @harold: I believe 16-bit emulation is still available, even in Windows 10, provided you're running the 32-bit edition.  Of course practically nobody does. :-)

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. How does the PC interface with the PIC, and why would the PC side need an interrupt handler if the PC / PIC interface is some standard component like a serial port? If there's also some reason to want to run in 16 bit real mode on the PC, Virtual PC or DOSBOX could be used.

Comment: I think protected mode is just for memory, should not apply to IO ports. You would need a kernel mode dll for that, and if it doesn't work, just switch to real mode?